# Algumas dúvidas sobre socket

Tags: c#, thread, socket

Estou dando uma olhada num exemplo da própria microsoft e estou com algumas dúvidas.

Exemplo retirado deste link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

Vamos imaginar um ambiente de chat via socket...
Devo estabelecer uma conexão socket sempre que for enviar uma mensagem?
Segue o metodo de exemplo:

```
private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Neste exemplo é criado a conexão, e enviado uma mensagem, logo em seguida aguarda o retorno da mensagem e por fim fecha a conexão.

Eu posso manter uma conexão aberta e enviar várias mensagens separadamente?
No caso do `sendDone.WaitOne()`, o que de fato este método faz?

Quando executo a comunicação numa thread separada, funciona perfeitamente porém ao executar o comando na thread principal o projeto fica travado, como se estivesse aguardando um retorno (que por sinal nunca chega rsrs)

No caso abaixo tenho um método que envia a informação para a conexão socket:

```
client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
```

onde `client` é do tipo `Socket`;

`byteData` representa a informação que estou enviando, qual é o melhor meio de converter um objeto com valores para byte e no lado do servidor converter de byte para o mesmo tipo de objeto?

minha intenção inicial é fazer um comunicador, tipo um servidor de batepapo, onde teria salas e grupos. Neste caso todo cliente também deveria ser um servidor para ficar sempre a escutar os recados do servidor?

No cliente eu posso criar uma thread que ficará exclusiva para "escutar" e executar as tarefas de acordo com o retorno?

Se tiver algum material educativo que aborde estes e mais detalhes me informe :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

> Eu posso manter uma conexão aberta e enviar várias mensagens
>   separadamente?

Pode! No caso de uma aplicação de chat, inclusive, você vai ter que deixar esse socket aberto, já que o servidor (ou o cliente, no caso de um chat P2P) tem que encontrar uma conexão aberta com a sua estação, e essa conexão será disponibilizada pela abertura do socket

> No caso do sendDone.WaitOne(), o que de fato este método faz?

Vi o código no MSDN, e sendDone, receiveDone e connectDone são cada um uma instância de um ManualResetEvent. É um jeito de notificar várias threads de que uma determinada operação foi executada. Neste caso, quando eu envio / recebo mensagens ou mesmo me conecto ao servidor com sucesso, eu chamo o método Set. Ao usar o WaitOne em uma thread, você fica esperando que outra thread chame o método Set para liberar a continuação.

> qual é o melhor meio de converter um objeto com valores para byte e no
>   lado do servidor converter de byte para o mesmo tipo de objeto?

Existem alguns jeitos de se fazer isso. Se você estiver enviando uma simples string, por exemplo, pode chamar o método Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string); já se estiver enviando um tipo complexo, pode utilizar a classe BinaryFormatter

> Neste caso todo cliente também deveria ser um servidor para ficar
>   sempre a escutar os recados do servidor?

Considerando que você precisa fazer grupos, recomendo que faça um servidor central e gerencie as trocas de mensagens por ali; No entanto, de alguma forma o seu socket será responsável por receber e enviar dados de/para o servidor

> No cliente eu posso criar uma thread que ficará exclusiva para
>   "escutar" e executar as tarefas de acordo com o retorno?

Pode.